# Pass value to included url file

Tags: php, url

I include my file from domain to another domain in different servers 
It works but the problem I can't pass variables to my included file

I Mean like

```
includedurl.php


$dbh= new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=example', 'example', 'example');

$stmt = $dbh->prepare('SELECT * FROM accs WHERE Email = ? AND Password = ?');
$stmt->execute(array($Email,$Password));

if($stmt->rowCount() = 1) {
   echo 'hi';
}else{
   echo 'Wrong email or password';
}
```

`index.php`

```
$Email = 'example@example.com';
$Password = 'example';
include('http://example.com/includedurl.php');
```

Comment: so what was the problem

Comment: i can't pass the variable

Answer (score 1):

When you include a URL, you are making an HTTP request to the server. The PHP on that server will be compiled and executed by that server before the response gets to your code.

If you want to send data then you need to do so as you would with any other HTTP request (e.g. in a query string or POST body).

Comment: didn't understand can u explain?

Comment: i mean can you give me some example code so i can understand